# how to create sqoop mysql to hive partition?

Tags: python, mysql, hadoop, hive, sqoop

create sqoop mysql to hive partition? I need Clear explanation below my code

```
    sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/arun  --table account --username root --password hadoop -m 1  --hive-partition-key "name" --hive-partition-value "arun" --hive-database company  --create-hive-table  --hive-table account5  --target-dir /user/sqooptest21
```

Comment: if need  2 partitions use below code : ** `sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/arun  --table account --username root --password hadoop -m 3  --hive-partition-value 2 --hive-import --hive-database company --create-hive-table --hive-table account123  --target-dir /tmp/customer/arunn`   **                                                                                                                                                                                                                                and check the partitioned output  /user/hive/warehouse

Answer (score 0):

based on your command.

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/arun  --table account --username root --password hadoop -m 1  --hive-partition-key "name" --hive-partition-value "arun" --hive-database company  --create-hive-table  --hive-table account5  --target-dir /user/sqooptest21
```

you are going to import your a database table from mysql to hdfs(migration).

- --connect: your are connecting to your database named "arun" in SQL.
- --table:   the name of your SQLtable you are going to migrate "account"
- --username & --password: username and password of MySQL server.
- -m:        the no of mappers to be used to migrate data.
- --hive-partition-key: name of a hive field(name field in your case) to partition are sharded on
- --hive-partiton-value: string-value(arun) that serves as partition key for this imported into hive in this job
- --create-hive-table: if set, then the job will fail if the target hive table exits. By default this property is false
- --hive-table : name of the table in the which the data is to be stored in hive
- --target-dir : name of the directory in hdfs where the migrated data from SQL is stored.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: But its not working,i didnt get patitioned output.its import table all the values.i expect partitioned output

Comment: In the first command you didn't use the --hive-import argument.And check whether --hive-database is a valid argument. There is no such argument in the sqoop documentation.refer [this](http://hadooped.blogspot.in/2013/06/apache-sqoop-part-2-for-data.html) for reference.